# Pandas cumsum on a separate column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue using Pandas and cumsum which is not behaving as I was expecting so was wondering if anyone could shed some light on how this works.

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
|     |price    |flag  |cum_sum  |
|-----|---------|------|---------|
|0    |2        |1     |2        |
|1    |5        |1     |7        |
|2    |8        |1     |15       |
|3    |9        |0     |0        |
|4    |12       |0     |0        |
|5    |2        |1     |17       |
```

Currently the code looks as follows:

```
df['cum_sum'] = df.groupby(by=['flag','price']).sum().groupby(level=[1]).cumsum()
```

I only want it to sum a column where a flag is specified. I feel like this should be simple but i'm missing something fundamental. The dataset is huge so was not looking for any loops or iteration answers.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: So you only want have a cummulative sum for the `price` column when `flag` is 1?

Comment: if you wish to sum() the price, did you try "df.groupby('flag')['price'].cumsum()"? your part of query after the sum() seems to be irrelevant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have most of what you want. If you want null values (NaN) for 0-flags then do this:

```
df['cum_sum'] = df[df['flag'] == 1]['price'].cumsum()
```

`flag  price  cum_sum
0     1      2      2.0
1     1      5      7.0
2     1      8     15.0
3     0      9      NaN
4     0     12      NaN
5     1      2     17.0`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
In [15]: df.price.mul(df.flag).cumsum().mul(df.flag)
Out[15]:
0     2
1     7
2    15
3     0
4     0
5    17
dtype: int64
```